# howw to make rating for each actor , separately for male and female customers?

Tags: sql

the exercise is:

Report the number of movie rentals and the average rating for each actor, separately for male and female customers.

Report only actors with more than 5 movie rentals.

code:

```
SELECT a.name,  c.gender,
       COUNT(*) AS number_views, 
       AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM renting as r
LEFT JOIN customers AS c
ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN actsin as ai
ON r.movie_id = ai.movie_id
LEFT JOIN actors as a
ON ai.actor_id = a.actor_id

GROUP BY a.name ___ -- For each actor, separately for male and female customers
HAVING AVG(r.rating) IS NOT NULL 
where movie_id > 5 -- Report only actors with more than 5 movie rentals
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC, number_views DESC;
```

how to make  rating for each actor, separately for male and female customers?

renting table

| renting_id | customer_id | movie_id | rating | date_renting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41 | 8 | null | 2018-10-09 |
| 2 | 10 | 29 | 10 | 2017-03-01 |

customers table

| customer_id | name | country | gender | date_of_birth | date_account_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Wolfgang Ackermann | Austria | male | 1971-11-17 | 2018-10-15 |
| 3 | Daniela Herzog | Austria | female | 1974-08-07 | 2019-02-14 |

actor table

| actor_id | name | year_of_birth | nationality | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abbie Cornish | 1982 | Australia | female |
| 2 | Adam Sandler | 1966 | USA | male |

actsin table

| actsin_id | movie_id | actor_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | 1 |
| 2 | 56 | 2 |

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful, and a view of your expected output based on the table data you show as an example.
If at all possible create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: Please dont SPAM Tags, are you using MySQL OR Postgress. They are not the same thing and answers may be very different for each DB Server. I have removed the conflicting DBMS's please add back the one you are using

Comment: Use case expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: @RiggsFolly updating

Comment: @jarlh updating

Comment: We are still waiting for actsin table, and the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh add actsin table.and I don't know what to put instead of a pass(near GROUP BY).